# question on applying mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was given a problem:(True/False)There exists a function $f : [0, 1] → \mathbb{R}$ with $f(0) = 0, f(1) = 3$, and $f'
(x) ≤ 2$ for all $x ∈ [0, 1]$.

I said this assertion was false because of the mean value theorem. There is some $c \in (0,1)$ with $f'(c)=3$ if the above assertions are satisfied. My question is, is it okay to apply the mean value theorem to this problem?

Comment: Yes: do you recall the assumptions for MVT to hold? Can you see: How does the info presented in the question tell you those assumptions hold?

Comment: Yea I just didn't know if a function that was undifferentiable at some point in $[0,1]$ would qualify as satisfying the conditions in this problem but I guess it is obvious.

Comment: If the derivative is at most 2 everywhere on $[0,1]$, then the derivative better exist everywhere on $[0,1]$!

Comment: Yea that was I solved it with the MVT.

Comment: Your doubt about the function being differentiable everywhere is well-founded. It is implicit in the assertion that $f'(x)\le 2$ for all $x\in[0,1]$, but it should really have been explicitly asserted in the statement of the question. (To nitpick further: it should also state that $f'(x)\le 2$ for $x\in(0,1)$, not $[0,1]$; and that $f$ is right-continuous at $0$ and left-continuous at $1$, or some such equivalent formulation. But that is, I would say, a less egregious error.)